# CORS error on expressjs server hosted on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have made simple expressJS server with nodemailer and have hosted it on aws elastic beanstalk, after which I was provided a 'http' link for the same, but I entered that link in my website which was hosted on netlify, it threw an error stating that an 'https' website cannot access 'http' website, so I converted my aws link to 'https' link, but after that I got an cors error from my netlify website.

I've tried multiple things, including importing the cors library from express like this:

`

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: [
        /\.netlify\.app$/,
    ],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST']
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

`

or setting headers like:

`

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
```

`but these methods did not work either, I always get the same error:`access has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
Please Help me resolve this error, I want to enable cors.

Comment: does it work when you set origin to "*"? if yes, the origin is most probably wrong

Comment: No, still the same error, "No 'Acces-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I suspect that cors are defined after the method. It needs to be before.

Comment: I have firstly required all the libraries (express, morgan, cors, dotenv), then I defined a new `app = express()`, after which I defined cors, like this `const corsOptions = {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ['GET', 'POST']
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));` . Should I change the order?

Comment: it still looks ok. but the problem is not reproduceable. you can share reprodecable code using some playground

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm dumb in this scenario, I needed to setup https redirection in load balancer in aws elastic beanstalk, I used dthe wrong port in the instance port for http I needed the port '80'.

I'm really sorry to waste your time :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Derviş Kayımbaşıoğlu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1118978/dervi%C5%9F-kay%C4%B1mba%C5%9F%C4%B1o%C4%9Flu) for helping me.

If anyone is facing this issue, kindly check your load balancer settings, it requires a https redirect to http, so the port for https is '443' and for http(instance port) is '80'.